# unsubscribe is not a function in an observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a function that should be a base for a stopwatch. It returns some values for different methods. I use a subscribtion for an observable there, and I want to unsubscribe from it when my timer is stopped, but it returns an error "TypeError: this.customIntervalObservable.unsubscribe is not a function"

What might be the problem and how can I fix it?

My observable code:

```
      customIntervalObservable = Observable.create((observer) => {
    let count = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      observer.next(count);
      count = count + this.deg;
    }, 1000);
  });
```

My method code is:

```
  stopWatch(isSubscribed) {
    if (isSubscribed) {
      this.customIntervalObservable.subscribe((sec) => {
        this.ss = sec;
        this.getSeconds(this.ss);
        if (this.ss / (60 * this.deg) === 1) {
          this.ss = 0;
          this.mm = this.mm + 6;
          this.getMinutes(this.mm);

          if (this.mm / (60 * this.deg) === 1) {
            this.mm = 0;
            this.hh = this.hh + 6;
            this.getHours(this.hh);
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.customIntervalObservable.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't unsubscribe an `Observable`, just a `Subscription`.

First, get a reference to that subscription:

```
stopWatch(isSubscribed) {
    if (isSubscribed) {
      this.subscription = this.customIntervalObservable.subscribe(...)
    ...
    }
}
```

Then, in the else-path, you can write:

```
else {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as your answer to close this question. Thanks!